# Spring BindStatus path for nested Map property

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a model object like so :

```
class Model {

    SubModel submodel = new SubModel();

}

class SubModel {

    Map props = Maps.newHashmap();
}
```

and in jsp i want to bind them to inputs like so :

```
<spring:bind path="submodel.props['key']">
....input...
....errors.....
</spring:bind>
```

And I'm getting next exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.AbstractDescriptor.<init>(AbstractDescriptor.java:35)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.ClassDescriptor.<init>(ClassDescriptor.java:31)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor.<init>(TypeDescriptor.java:563)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor.valueOf(TypeDescriptor.java:125)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.findEditor(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:125)
```

Is it possible to use BindStatus with nested map ? 
BTW, jstl works, but I want a cleaner way to bind values and errors.

Comment: Not enough code to really understand where you are getting the `submodel` you are trying to access in the spring tag.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be `submodel.props[key]` - based on http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-beans-conventions